# How to run python script on pi without logging in everytime

Tags: python, boot

I want my pi to run a python script on it everytime I plug it into any power source. 
My pi collects data from MSP430x and upload it on a cloud server. I want to keep it running all the time and I can't afford to keep it connected to my laptop for whole day. 
Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

easiest and more robust way would be using `crontab` instead of messing with `rc.local` or (worse) creating broken daemon scripts. keyword `@reboot` does all the magic:

```
$ crontab -e
no crontab for pi - using an empty one

Select an editor.  To change later, run 'select-editor'.
  1. /bin/ed
  2. /bin/nano        <---- easiest
  3. /usr/bin/vim.tiny

Choose 1-3 [2]: 2
crontab: installing new crontab
$ crontab -l
# m h  dom mon dow   command
@reboot /home/pi/script_to_run_on_reboot
```

just make sure your `/home` partition is not encrypted and is already mounted during the boot process, otherwise you might need to change the place for your script.

Comment: That is an interesting way of going about it.  Thanks for letting me know about `@reboot`.

Answer (score 3):

## rc.local (Simple)

You can run commands by adding them to **/etc/rc.local**.  Each command/script must not have any ouput and **/etc/rc.local** must `exit 0` when it completes.

Here is an example:

```
python /full/path/to/py.py arg1, arg2 > /dev/null
bash /home/user/startup-script.sh > /dev/null
exit 0
```

## crontab ([lenik](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/19877/622))

An easy and robust way would be using `crontab` instead of messing with `rc.local` or (worse) creating broken daemon scripts. keyword `@reboot` does all the magic:

```
$ crontab -e
no crontab for pi - using an empty one

Select an editor.  To change later, run 'select-editor'.
  1. /bin/ed
  2. /bin/nano        <---- easiest
  3. /usr/bin/vim.tiny

Choose 1-3 [2]: 2
crontab: installing new crontab
$ crontab -l
# m h  dom mon dow   command
@reboot /home/pi/script_to_run_on_reboot
```

Make sure your `/home` partition is not encrypted and is already mounted during the boot process, otherwise you might need to change the place for your script.

## init.d (Daemon)

You could create an upstart script and place it into your **/etc/init.d/** directory.  You would then need to make sure it's executable and add it to startup via `update-rc.d`.

- vim /etc/init.d/startup-daemon
- chmod +x /etc/init.d/startup-daemon
- update-rc.d startup-daemon defaults
- update-rc.d startup-daemon enable

You will need to spend some time learning about [daemons](https://wiki.debian.org/Daemon), if you chose this method.

---

#### Note

In the future, be sure to give some specs, such as your operating system.